# Auto resize the panels of SplitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

in a splitcontainer if I write splitcontainer1.panel1.visible = false;  it does not cause the panel2 to fill all the space of the splitcontainer but this is what I actually need.
can you please help me how to achieve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`Panel1Collapsed` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1collapsed.aspx) to true instead.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem,you can use Panel1Collapsed and Panel1Expanded bool property is suitable making true or false as u need asper requirement...